# Rewrite/Redirect a specific URL with masking

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, masking

I need to add Rewrite/Redirect statements in my .htaccess to redirect a specific url to a different .php page with masking. The goal is when someone hits:

[www.mydomain.com/sandbox](http://www.mydomain.com/sandbox)

i need it to go to:

server.mydomain.com/directoryname/phpprogram.php. But I need it to mask so the address bar will still show [www.mydomain.com/sandbox](http://www.mydomain.com/sandbox)

Appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share your htaccess file in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mod-rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to maks your URLs.

The following rule in an `htaccess` file should do the trick :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^sandbox/?$ /directoryname/phpprogram.php [L]
```

This will internally map a request for `example.com/sandbox` to `example.com/directoryname/phpprogram.php`  .
The `/?` in the regular expression pattern above matches the traling slash as an optional character so the rule will also match `example.com/sandbox/` .